# Jquery all my functions work except the following

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
(function($) {
  var selectIds = new Array();
  var sortOnSelect = false;
  var nameModifier = "tsms";
  function removeFormField() {
    $(id).remove();
  }
```

All the other functions after this work. This function says it undefined using firebug.

removeFormField is not defined

Another function creates this field and the top function is suppose to remove it.

```
<label for="txt4">Field 4&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="txt4" name="txt[]" size="20">&nbsp;&nbsp;<a onclick="removeFormField(&quot;#row4&quot;); return false;" href="#">Remove</a></label>
```

Comment: This is a truncated snippet. Your function merely declares three variables and a function that doesn't even use any of the variables. 

Also, if you're using jQuery, you should be attaching the onclick handler to the a element programmatically, and not via <a onclick =...

Comment: In addition to what Nick is saying, you should also be initializing arrays using 



var selectIDs = [];

Answer (score 3):

You need to put  your function outside of the document ready function then call it from within.

```
(function($) {
   var selectIds = new Array();
   var sortOnSelect = false;
   var nameModifier = "tsms";
   removeFormField();
});

function removeFormField() {
   $(id).remove();
}
```

Comment: Is this intended to be a plugin or a startup function?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the problem where the function is declared in the jQuery ready() handler, your function as written does not take an input value.

It should be:

```
function removeFormField(id) {
    $(id).remove();
}
```